# MonoGame-based animation system fails to change animation

Tags: c#, monogame

We have a problem with the animation. The problem is that it won't play the right animation. We are using a spritesheet with 4 frames: idle, movement and so on. Here's the code we are using:

```
class Animator : Component, IUpdateable
{
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private int currentindex;
    private float timeElasped;
    private float fps;
    private Rectangle[] rectangles;
    private string animationName;
    private Dictionary<string, Animation> animations;

    public Animator(GameObject gameObject) : base(gameObject)
    {
        animations = new Dictionary<string, Animation>();
        fps = 5;
        spriteRenderer = (SpriteRenderer)gameObject.GetComponent("SpriteRenderer");
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        timeElasped += GameWorld.Instance.deltaTime;
        currentindex = (int)(timeElasped * fps);

        if (currentindex > rectangles.Length - 1)
        {
            GameGetGameObject.OnAnimationDone(animationName);
            timeElasped = 0;
            currentindex = 0;



        }

        spriteRenderer.Rectangle = rectangles[currentindex];
    }

    public void CreateAnimation(string name, Animation animation)
    {
        animations.Add(name, animation);
    }

    public void PlayAnimation(string animationName)
    {
        if (this.animationName != animationName)
        {
            this.rectangles = animations[animationName].GetRectangle;
            this.spriteRenderer.Rectangle = rectangles[0];
            this.spriteRenderer.Offset = animations[animationName].GetOffSet;
            this.animationName = animationName;
            this.fps = animations[animationName].GetFps;

            timeElasped = 0;
            currentindex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

That's part of the animation code.
Next is the player class that uses the animation code.

```
class Player : Component, IUpdateable, ILoadable, IAnimateable
{
    private float speed = 50;

    public Player(GameObject gameObject) : base(gameObject)
    {

    }

    public Animator Animator
    {
        get { return (Animator)GameGetGameObject.GetComponent("Animator"); }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Move();

    }

    public void Move()
    {
        Vector2 translation = Vector2.Zero;
        KeyboardState KeyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (KeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            translation += new Vector2(0, -1);

            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingZero");
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingOne");
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingTwo");

        }

        if (KeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {


            translation += new Vector2(0, 1);
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingZero");
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingOne");
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingTwo");


        }


        if (KeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {

            translation += new Vector2(-1, 0);

            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingZero");
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingOne");
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingTwo");

        }


        if (KeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {


            translation += new Vector2(1, 0);

            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingZero");
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingOne");
            Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingTwo");



        }

       Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingZero");
        GameGetGameObject.GetTransform().Translate(translation * GameWorld.Instance.deltaTime * speed);

    }

    public void CreateAnimations()
    {
        Animator.CreateAnimation("Idle",new Animation(4,0,0,42,32,4,Vector2.Zero));
        Animator.CreateAnimation("MovingZero", new Animation(4, 0, 1, 42, 32, 4, Vector2.Zero));
        Animator.CreateAnimation("MovingOne", new Animation(4, 0, 2, 42, 32, 4, Vector2.Zero));
        Animator.CreateAnimation("MovingTwo", new Animation(4, 0, 3, 42, 32, 4, Vector2.Zero));

    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        CreateAnimations();
        Animator.PlayAnimation("Idle");
    }

    public void OnAnimationDone(string animationName)
    {
    }
}
```

We are using the component-pattern. This is our animation component:

```
class Animation : Component
{
    private float Fps;
    private Vector2 Offset;
    private Rectangle[] rectangles;
    public float GetFps { get; set; }
    public Vector2 GetOffSet { get; set; }

    public Rectangle[] GetRectangle
    {
       get { return rectangles; }
       set { rectangles = value; }
    }

    public Animation(int frames, int yPos,int xStratFrame, int width, int height, float fps, Vector2 offset)
    {
        rectangles = new Rectangle[frames];
        Offset = offset;

        Fps = fps;

        for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
        {
            rectangles[i] = new Rectangle((i + xStratFrame) * width,yPos,width,height);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the code for the sprite renderer:

```
class SpriteRenderer : Component, ILoadable, IDrawable
{
    private GameObject gameObject;
    public Texture2D sprite;
    private string spriteName;
    private float layerDepth;
    public Vector2 Offset { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }

    public SpriteRenderer(GameObject gameObject, string spriteName, float layerDepth)
    {
        this.gameObject = gameObject;
        this.spriteName = spriteName;
        this.layerDepth = layerDepth;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Update();

    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        this.sprite = content.Load<Texture2D>(spriteName);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, gameObject.GetTransform().GetPosition(), Rectangle, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Basically the player can move and it plays a part of the animation but not all of it. How do I fix the animation playback?

Answer (score 1):

you reset the animation each time

```
    }

   Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingZero");
    GameGetGameObject.GetTransform().Translate(translation * GameWorld.Instance.deltaTime * speed);

}
```

and

```
        Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingZero");
        Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingOne");
        Animator.PlayAnimation("MovingTwo");
```

won't work. you have to wait to finish the animation first or all statements will be called first, then the last will be rendered

monogame have 2 loops, the draw and update loop.
you need a counter that counts the frames, each frame you have to increment it and check which frame now should be rendered.

Comment: ehm so what exactly do u mean? i am honestly a big noob at monogame we had one week of learning basicly so i am abit bronze on this spot. is there a chance u could show how?

Comment: if you upload it, I could try to fix it :)

Comment: let me upload it

Comment: if u like to help us here is the full project <a http://www.filedropper.com/giftman

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n62q4ovn0jhxqlv/giftmanFixed.zip?dl=0

Comment: wow thanks mate :D Really GRATEFul :D this solved so much for us :D thanks once again

Comment: actually i got a question what if we want to only play the animation if we press on  a key?

Comment: then just start after pressing it :) currently it automatic starts. you can check the vector in the update block. if this vector is zero then set the animation to idle. if not start the animation you want.

Comment: i actually found it out in middle of the night :D but again thanks all for your help